# Is there any way to reduce the PostgreSQL performance deviation between the multiple iterations?

Tags: postgresql

NOPM values captured with HammerDB-v4.3 scripts (schema_tpcc.tcl and
test_tpcc.tcl ) for multiple trails.
The expected performance deviation between the multiple trials should be less
than 2%, but observed more.

Hardware configuration

```
Architecture        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s)      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              256
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-255
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  64
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        8
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K 
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            16384K
OS: RHEL8.4
RAM SIZE:512
SSD:1TB
```

Postgresql.conf

```
autovacuum_max_workers = 16
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 3000
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
checkpoint_timeout = '15min'
cpu_tuple_cost = 0.03
effective_cache_size = '350GB'
listen_addresses = '*'
maintenance_work_mem = '2GB'
max_connections = 1000
max_wal_size = '128GB'
random_page_cost = 1.1
shared_buffers = '128GB'
wal_buffers = '1GB'
work_mem = '128MB'
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
```

HammerDB Scripts
>>cat schema.tcl

```
    #!/bin/tclsh
    dbset db pg
    diset connection pg_host localhost
    diset connection pg_port 5432
    diset tpcc pg_count_ware 400
    diset tpcc pg_num_vu 50
    print dict
    buildschema
    waittocomplete
```

RUN TEST on i.e. start with 1VU then 2, 4, etc

```
  | Virtual Users | Trail-1(NOPM) | Trail-2(NOPM) | %diff   |
  |---------------|---------------|---------------|---------|
  | 12            | 99390         |     92913     | 6.516752|
  | 140           | 561429        |    525408     | 6.415949| 
  | 192           | 636016        |    499574     | 21.4526 |
  | 230           | 621644        |    701882     | 12.9074 |
```

Comment: Do you expect someone to buy a machine like yours, install HammerDB, repeat your experiment and analyze the case?

Comment: Reproduction of the question will be nearly impossible and it's not clear what the question is and the reasoning of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a comprehensive answer to this question on [HammerDB discussions](https://github.com/TPC-Council/HammerDB/discussions/286).

You make an assumption that PostgreSQL will scale linearly for an intensive OLTP workload on 256 logical CPUs of a particular type. However, if a workload experiences high contention then performance will not be as expected on a particular hardware/software combination due to locking and latching - this is to be expected. Your experience may be different on different hardware (with the same database) and/or a different database (on the same hardware). For example, you may find a higher core count results in lower performance as the additional cores increase contention, lowering throughput.

You need to follow the advice in the discussions post and analyze the wait events using the HammerDB v4.3 Graphical metrics viewer for pg_active_session_history or with SQL directly. This will direct you to exactly the cause of contention (with a particular hardware/software combination - LWLock is highlighted in pink in the viewer or look for this in the query output). If this does not enable you to diagnose the issues directly, then employing a PostgreSQL consultant would be necessary to explain the issue for you.